# XSD element vs type declarations in separate namespaces?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xmllint

I have a number of XSD schemas that are imported by another one. When validating against the main wrapper-like XSD, the validator does not seem to associate the type to the correct XSD. It seem to be mixing up the namespaces in a way.

As a minimum example, consider the following two XSDs, each defining their own type and namespace:

**a.xsd** defining an `a-type`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://a"
           targetNamespace="http://a"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="a-type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

**b.xsd** defining a `b-type`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://b"
           targetNamespace="http://b"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="qualified" >

  <xs:simpleType name="b-type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

**ab.xsd** that defines it own `ab-type`, making use of the above defined types:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:a="http://a"
           xmlns:b="http://b"
           xmlns:tns="http://ab"
           targetNamespace="http://ab"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="qualified" >

  <xs:import namespace="http://a" schemaLocation="a.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="http://b" schemaLocation="b.xsd"/>

  <xs:complexType name="ab-type">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:element name="a-tag" type="a:a-type"/>
      <xs:element name="b-tag" type="b:b-type"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ab-tag" type="tns:ab-type"/>

</xs:schema>
```

When I validate it against the following XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ab:ab-tag
    xmlns:ab="http://ab"
    xmlns:a="http://a"
    xmlns:b="http://b">
  <a:a-tag>A</a:a-tag>
  <b:b-tag>B</b:b-tag>
</ab:ab-tag>
```

I get the following error from `xmllint --schema ab.xsd ab.xml`:

> ab.xml:6: element `a-tag`: Schemas validity error : Element `{http://a}a-tag`: This element is not expected. Expected is ( `{http://ab}a-tag` ).
>   ab.xml fails to validate

I also have a similar error when validating with `xsd11-validator.jar`. So, even though I am specifying in `ab.xsd` that the `a-tag` is of type `a:a-tag`, it still seems to try to associate it with the namespace from `ab`.

Comment: Impressive [mcve] -- great question!

Answer (score 0):

A ***type*** being defined in an XSD from another XML namespace is not the same as an ***element*** being defined that other XML namespace.

To place `a-tag` in the `http://a` namespace, you must actually place an element declaration in that namespace...

### a.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:tns="http://a"
  targetNamespace="http://a"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="a-type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="a-tag" type="tns:a-type"/>
</xs:schema>
```

### b.xsd

Similarly, declare `b-tag` in the `http://b` namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:tns="http://b"
  targetNamespace="http://b"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="qualified" >

  <xs:simpleType name="b-type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="b-tag" type="tns:b-type"/>
</xs:schema>
```

### ab.xsd

In **ab.xsd**, change from `xs:element/@name` to `@ref`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:a="http://a"
  xmlns:b="http://b"
  xmlns:tns="http://ab"
  targetNamespace="http://ab"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="qualified" >

  <xs:import namespace="http://a" schemaLocation="a.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="http://b" schemaLocation="b.xsd"/>

  <xs:complexType name="ab-type">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:element ref="a:a-tag"/>
      <xs:element ref="b:b-tag"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ab-tag" type="tns:ab-type"/>
</xs:schema>
```

### ab.xml

**ab.xml** is alright as is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ab:ab-tag
  xmlns:ab="http://ab"
  xmlns:a="http://a"
  xmlns:b="http://b">
  <a:a-tag>A</a:a-tag>
  <b:b-tag>B</b:b-tag>
</ab:ab-tag>
```

---

Defined as above, **ab.xml** is now valid against **ab.xsd**.

Comment: That works fine for this simple minimal example, but this solution implies that you actually reference the _entire_ element including the name, not just its type. If we are to define two elements with different names and both using the same type `a:a-tag`, it would mean that you need to add that element to the definition to the `a.xsd, making the xsd no longer agnostic.

Comment: Take care not to confuse *declaration* with *use*:  That an element must be *declared* in an XSD with a `targetNamespace` that matches its namespace in no way limits the *use* of that element in other namespaces.  Elements are referenced by their `QName`, which includes both the namespace part and the local part.  Elements with different `Qnames` can have the same or different types.